# Inserting date into derby database in string.format using placeholders

Tags: sql, insert, derby, string.format

I'm having a really messy problem with inserting START_DATE (defined as a DATE type when creating the table) into my table, using placeholders.
So I know that in the string.format I shall define the START_DATE as 'DD.MM.YYYY', but how do I use the placeholders? What do I use, the %s placeholder? Where and how?

I have been trying for hours but in vain. Can you show me how to solve this out?

```
String sql = String.format(
            "insert into Company(COMPANY_ID, password, START_DATE) "
            + "values(%d,'%s','%s'd'%s'd.'%s'm'%s'm.'%s'y'%s'y'%s'y'%s'y')", 
            COMPANY_ID, password, START_DATE);
```

For this I get the error: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'

Comment: You said you've made several attempts already.  Can you paste the code for the attempts you've made?

Comment: And don't just include your code, also include the results (error messages, thrown exceptions, database results, etc.).

Comment: That is a horrible way of inserting data. Use a `PreparedStatement` with placeholders and pass an instance of `LocalDate` (and `int` for the numbers). Do **NOT** concatenate input values like that into SQL strings.